# Can't delete orphaned email messages: Insufficient Access Rights On Object Id

Tags: email, delete, insufficient-privileges

The system overview tells me that the org contains a number of email messages. Using SOQL, I see that parentId is always empty. So I think that the email messages are orphaned. I cannot delete them, whatever method I use, I always get the message: "Insufficient Access Rights On Object Id".

How can I get rid of these things? Obviously I have sysadmin profile.

My Apex script that fails:

```
delete [SELECT id FROM EmailMessage];
```

Edit: I added some attributes to my query, to see which user sent which mails, and it turns out I can delete mails that I have sent, but not mails that others users have sent.

Comment: How are you trying to delete these records?

Comment: I have tried Apex, to delete a selection of email messages, as well as the option in Workbench to delete individual records, given an Id.

Comment: Please check the ID you have given to delete the record. You could also post the apex code to dig further

Comment: I have posted the code. The ids all start with 02s. The semi-official description of that is 'HTML_COMPONENT'.

Comment: Can you post the whole code or are you using execute anonymous to execute only this code?

Comment: That's the whole code, I'm using Developer Console to execute it.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. It is amazing how annoying Salesforce can be. I, as a System Admin, can't delete emails that are using more than 1/5 of my org's storage capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I know of is to perform the delete operation when logged in as the user who sent the EmailMessage record.

This coincides with what Sander observed that he was able to delete emails he sent but not those sent from other users.